# Is there a generic TimeZoneInfo For Central Europe?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

Is there a generic TimeZoneInfo for Central Europe that takes into consideration both CET and CEST into one?

I have an app that is doing the following:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time"); 
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(someDate, tzi.BaseUtcOffset);
var utcDate = dto.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;
```

The problem is that this is returning the wrong utcDate because the BaseUtcOffset is +1 instead of +2. It appears that CET has DST as well and depending on the time of the year it is  +1 or +2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to applaud mgnoonan's answer of using Noda Time :) But if you're feeling less adventurous...

You're already using the right time zone - but you shouldn't be using [`BaseUtcOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset.aspx) which is *documented* not to be about DST:

> Gets the time difference between the current time zone's standard time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

It can't possibly take DST into consideration when you're not providing it a `DateTime` to fetch the offset for :)

Assuming `someDate` is a `DateTime`, you could use:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(someDate, tzi.GetUtcOffset(someDate));
```

Or just [`ConvertTimeToUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381744.aspx):

```
var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(someDate, tzi);
```

Note that you should work out what you want to do if your local time occurs twice due to a DST transition, or doesn't occur at all.

Comment: I knew I should have just waited for you to answer. ;)

Comment: Great explanation. Although Noda Time might be the right tool, this worked and is the best solution for the current project.

Comment: Just a minor comment: ConvertTimeToUtc is now a static method so you need to call
var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(someDate, tzi)

Comment: @Eoin: How odd - I wonder how I got that wrong. Will fix. (There are a bunch of static methods in `TimeZoneInfo` taking a `TimeZoneInfo` as a parameter. I've never understood why...)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [Noda Time](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/) can help you out?

Comment: Will definitely take Noda Time into consideration next time I use dates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using .Net Core referance [ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc?view=net-8.0)

```
        // Get Current Central European Standard Time
        DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeZoneInfo cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
        DateTime cetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, cet);
        Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}", cet.IsDaylightSavingTime(cetTime) ? cet.DaylightName : cet.StandardName, cetTime);

        // Output:
        // Time in Central European Standard Time zone: 08-03-2024 05:26:03
```