# Incorrect UTC Datetime Calculated based on TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a timezoneinfo Central Europe Standard Time, which is showing UTC +01:00,
when i execute the code it shows 2 hrs before time instead of 1 hr.
Below is the sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strTimeZoneInfo = "Central Europe Standard Time";
        var datetimeDST = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-07-18 18:17:00");
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strTimeZoneInfo);
        var dtUTC= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(datetimeDST, timeZoneInfo);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dtUTC));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

So instead of 2019-07-18 17:17:00 i am getting 2019-07-18 16:17:00.
Can someone explain how to resolve this without using Noda or other external library.

Referred Below links but not clear how to resolve this problem.

- [UTC converted to Central Europe Standard Time is 2 hours in front not 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955650/utc-converted-to-central-europe-standard-time-is-2-hours-in-front-not-1)
- [Is there a generic TimeZoneInfo For Central Europe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019267/is-there-a-generic-timezoneinfo-for-central-europe)

Also referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949779/net-converting-datetime-to-utc-given-the-timezone)'s answer but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "which is showing UTC +01:00"? The time zone with ID of "Central Europe Standard Time" has an offset of UTC+2 on July 18th 2019 - ignore the confusing "standard time" part of the ID; it just means "central Europe" (e.g. Paris, Berlin). I'd *expect* it to convert to 16:17:00. That's all in the first link you included though, so I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying @JonSkeet, i followed your answers too, by "which is showing UTC +01:00" i mean when i debug timezone info shows (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague, so since its UTC +1 is should result in 2019-07-18 17:17:00 and not 2019-07-18 16:17:00.

Comment: No, that's just showing that the standard offset of the time zone is UTC+1. It doesn't mean that it's UTC+1 *all the time*. Right now, it's UTC+2 in all those places. `TimeZoneInfo` is doing the right thing, it's just your expectations that were incorrect.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: Thanks for the answers, its just the display name UTC+1 was creating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though "Central Europe Standard Time" is the `Id` property for that `TimeZoneInfo`, but it actually handles both Standard and Daylight time within that time zone depending on the date you're talking about. I understand it is confusing because that TimeZoneInfo includes "UTC+01:00" in the Display Name, even though it's currently in Daylight Savings Time.

But in this case, the date you're giving it is during a Daylight Savings Time period, so the offset should be `+02:00`, not `+01:00`. The library is producing the correct results.

```
var strTimeZoneInfo = "Central Europe Standard Time";
var datetimeDST = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-07-18 18:17:00");
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strTimeZoneInfo);
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.StandardName);
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.DaylightName);
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(datetimeDST));
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(datetimeDST));
var dtUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(datetimeDST, timeZoneInfo);
Console.WriteLine(dtUTC.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output:

> (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague
>   Central Europe Standard Time
>   Central Europe Daylight Time
>   True
>   02:00:00
>   07/18/2019 16:17:00